# How to display static values after report result in SSRS 2008 having two DataSet

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a SSRS report in BIDS 2008.
I just want to display some static values after resultset.
Suppose report display 100 records,so at the end of these records i want to display following result:

```
<----This is first block---><----This is second block--->
     RowLabel1   2.3             RowLabel4 55   
     RowLabel2   0.0             RowLabel5 5.5
     RowLabel3   2.3             RowLabel6 23
```

How to achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a Table Footer row (or rows) and enter your required values there. For example:

[image]

In the designer this is just a simple table with one Header row, one Detail row and two Footer rows. When run the report looks like this:

[image]

i.e. all rows in result set are displayed, then a couple of rows of static data.

**Edit after comment**

As per the comment there is a mix of DataSets involved, too.

For getting fields from another DataSet into the table, you can use an expression like:

```
=First(Fields!static1.Value, "DataSet2")
```

This specifies that the field is in a different Scope, i.e. *DataSet2*. You need to use `First` as there has to be some sort of aggregate expression in these cases; if your static data DataSet has only one row you could just as easily use another but `First` makes the most sense to me.

You could also consider:

- Treating the static data as a separate table below the first, but keeping both tables in a Rectangle to prevent them being split apart; this will look like one table to users.
- Add the static fields to every row in DataSet1, but only display them in the Footer rows.

Any of these could work, but the first option seems the best to me based on your description.

Comment: it's working fine thanks.I have created DataSet1 for 100 rows and DataSet2 for static values.When i tried to drag columns from DataSet2 an error message display: "Only fields from current dataset 'DataSet1' can be added " what should i do for this.

Comment: I've added a few options; based on your description something `=First(Fields!static1.Value, "DataSet2")` for the static data values might be easiest.

Comment: +1
your solution really helped me out.this is exactly what i wanted.thanks a lot.
stackoverflow awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a dataset with the following query:

```
SELECT 0 AS SortCol, <fields>
FROM <table>
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, "Extra value"
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, "Extra value"
...
```

Then create the tablix and sort on the SortCol. The 'Extra value' values will appear at the end of the tablix as if they were regular records.